# Is there a way to disable antialiasing for text in HTML components (Windows)?

Tags: html, windows, apache-flex, air, antialiasing

I have an AIR application that uses the HTML component to display a significant portion of content (I set the html myself, it is not loaded remotely).  The text displays normally on Mac (I think Mac antialiases all text by default).  However, on windows, the text displays anti-aliased regardless of the OS settings.  It ends up giving everything a red tint.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to control whether or not the text gets anti-aliased.  Does anyone know if there's a way to to this in Flex / AIR?

An example of what I'm talking about:

[image]
<sub>(source: [silentchris.com](http://silentchris.com/antialias2.png))</sub>

Comment: This is a fairly informative forum post on Adobe about ClearType and anti-aliasing with fonts in Flex/HTML: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/449201

Answer (score 2):

Windows typically uses "ClearType" [TM] for anti-aliasing.  Some people (myself included) hate it due to the exact image you posted above whereby if you eyesight is good, you see all the colors and not a soft anti-aliased black text on a white background. (hence it is also called "FuzzyType" by many)

There is a tool to "tweak" it, but it is limited.

I would Google/Search for "ClearType AIR" etc. and see if AIR provides any control over it.

[first relivent result I found](http://thanksmister.com/index.php/archive/adobe-air-runtime-font-differences/)

That all said, if the end user has turned it on, then maybe they like it that way.  I believe it is the default setting (on) in Windows XP and above.